# pass index value using ng-repeat in onchange and input type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-3rd-party

I have this html

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
<input type="file" class="form-control" ng-hide="true"
 accept="image/*" image="vm.venueImageList[i].file"
 file-upload="vm.venueImageList[i].file"
  resize-max-height="720"
  resize-max-width="1024"
   resize-quality="0.96"
   resize-type="image/jpg"
   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().vm.preUpload($index);"
   ng-image-compress/>
</div>
```

I want to pass the $index value but its says $index is undefined.
can someone help me how to pass $index to the angularjs funciton.

Here is the function

```
preUpload:function(index){
            vm.hideLoader[index].value=true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                if(vm.venueImageList[index].file.compressed.dataURL){
                    vm.venueImageList[index].url=vm.venueImageList[index].file.compressed.dataURL;
                    vm.venueImageList[index].file=vm.convertBaseToImage(vm.venueImageList[index].url);
                    vm.uploadFile(index);
                }

            },4000);

        },
```

Comment: Why not use an `ng-change` event? The reason `$index` isn't working is because it's an Angular expression and you're attempting to use a regular JS attribute.

Comment: I am not able to upload files using ng-repeat, I tried that first

Comment: You can try passing the index like `{{$index}}`

Comment: not working {{$index}}

Comment: @tymeJV The `ng-change` directive only works in conjunction with the `ng-model` directive and its controller. The stock `ng-model` directive does not work with `<input type=file`.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate it as an AngularJS expression on the parent scope:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" ng-hide="true"
       accept="image/*" image="vm.venueImageList[i].file"
       file-upload="vm.venueImageList[i].file"
       resize-max-height="720"
       resize-max-width="1024"
       resize-quality="0.96"
       resize-type="image/jpg"
       ̶o̶n̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶=̶"̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶.̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶)̶.̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶(̶)̶.̶v̶m̶.̶p̶r̶e̶U̶p̶l̶o̶a̶d̶(̶$̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶)̶;̶"̶ 
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().$parent.$eval('vm.preUpload($index)');"
       ng-image-compress
    />
</div>
```

The [`ng-image-compress`](https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress) directive uses an isolate scope. The `vm` object is not passed to that isolate scope.